# Shortest prime number generator we could come up with?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I worked with a friend on the following prime number generator. Our goal was to make it as short and as fast as possible. This is what we came up with:

```
def p(n): # will print out primes between 0 and n
  s=[True]*(n/2)
  for i in range(int((n/2-1)/2) >> 1):
    for j in range((i*(i+3)<<1)+3,n/2,(i<<1)+3): s[j]=False
  return [2] + [((i<<1)+3) for i in range(n/2) if (s[i])]
print p(input()) # input number for n
```

Can it be made any faster? Also, it crashes due to memory errors if numbers larger than 10<sup>10</sup> are inputted. Can this be fixed to make it more memory efficient?

Comment: I removed the part of your question asking for it to be shortened, since that is off-topic and this is not a code golfing site.  Please do not revert further edits.

Comment: @syb0rg sorry about that. I wasn't aware of code-golfing. i also removed a comment i made asking about this particular edit. thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 0. Quick comments on your code

1. Clearer function names and
   variables in your code. What does `p` mean, and what is `s`? I can
   guess, but please.
2. Include a [`docstring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac) or some indication of what your code does
3. Use the  [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprimesieve) module.

I did some quick speed comparisons of your function which you can see below.

```
magic1            21.9095528103 ms
magic2            26.5589244423 ms
Joseph Farah    1030.95786404   ms
```

I did 10 runs with primes up to \$2\$ million. Now note the big gap between the optimized functions and yours. Even if you were to speed up your code tenfold you would still be 10 times slower than the other functions.

> You can add as many horses you want to your cart, but it will never beat a ferrari.

With this in mind i propose three solutions

1. *Implement a better algorithm*
2. *Use Import*
3. *Give up*

### 1. New algorithm

Wikipedia can shed some light on how to find [larger primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes).

> For the large primes used in cryptography, it is usual to use a
>   modified form of sieving: a randomly chosen range of odd numbers of
>   the desired size is sieved against a number of relatively small primes
>   (typically all primes less than \$65,000\$). The remaining candidate
>   primes are tested in random order with a standard probabilistic
>   primality test such as the Baillie-PSW primality test or the
>   Miller-Rabin primality test for probable primes.

So in short you use for an example [Wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) to find possible primes, then use the [Rabin_primality_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) to test whether the candidates are primes. Without going too technical the Rabin_primality_test is a probabilistic test. If the function returns `True` p might be prime, if `False` we are guaranteed it is not. If n is composite then the Miller–Rabin primality test declares n probably prime with a probability at most \$4^{−k}\$. A friend told me banks used tested primes 80 times. The chances of a composite number passing \$80\$ tests is \$4^{-80}\$ which is in incredibly low number.

A comparison of many different sieves and ways to find primes can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n. I used the fastest one on my machine `primesfrom2to` to generate the results above

```
import numpy as np
def magic1(n):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python/3035188#3035188
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a array of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    sieve = np.ones(n/3 + (n%6==2), dtype=np.bool)
    sieve[0] = False
    for i in xrange(int(n**0.5)/3+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i+1|1
            sieve[      ((k*k)/3)      ::2*k] = False
            sieve[(k*k+4*k-2*k*(i&1))/3::2*k] = False
    return np.r_[2,3,((3*np.nonzero(sieve)[0]+1)|1)]
```

### 2. Use Import

[image]

Python is magical in the sense that you can find libaries which pretty much do anything. The best part is that [installing new packages is easy as \$\pi\$](https://docs.python.org/3.6/installing/index.html). There are many libaries for primes, I will mention a few below

- [primesieve](https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python)
- [primefac](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac)
- [pyprimesieve](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprimesieve)

`primesieve]` is Python bindings for the primesieve C++ library. It can generate list of primes at an incredible speed, and also has fast `nthprime` implementation. `primefac` is incredibly good at factoring primes, it can also generate primes, but is rather slow. `pyprimesieve` 
has functions such as `prime_sum` and has many nifty specialized functions.

So if you want a `golfed` answer the best you can get in terms of speed is

```
from primesieve import generate_primes

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print generate_primes(2*10**6)
```

### 3. Give up

Even if you are in your prime finding and generating large primes are incredibly hard. However this is a good thing as [primes are incredibly important in internet security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439870/why-are-primes-important-in-cryptography). If by some miracle you were to find an incredibly, incredibly fast prime generator it would break all the large banks and make payments over the net unsafe.

So perhaps it is a good thing your code is slow ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer! sorry for the terrible variable names, one of our goals was making the file size as small as possible. the resources look very helpful, thanks for those as well!

Comment: @JosephFarah Don't worry about file size--the length of variable names doesn't affect runtime performance in Python or any other "modern" language.

Answer (score 3):

#### Shorter code != Better code

Honestly, if I saw code like this in a production code base, I would immediately reformat it at least for readability.

I understand that writing shortest possible code can be *fun* (and there's even a [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) site for that), but it is not necessarily something you want to do for serious code, and since you asked for a review of it, here goes.

1. Spacing: There is virtually no white space other than what is absolutely required by the Python compiler to work. Lines like `for j in range((i*(i+3)<<1)+3,n/2,(i<<1)+3): s[j]=False` just make the code very hard to read and understand.
2. Naming: As N3buchadnezzar [mentioned](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132970/42632), clearer naming would make this code much better. Meaningful naming is a key skill in writing programs that others (and your future self) can maintain effectively.
3. Documentation: Again as mentioned, short [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) / documentation to describe what this function is for is just a good habit to make in any programming language.

**Edit:** I removed the function argument type hint as this is a Python 3.5 addition (was originally `def get_primes(n: int)`) and would not compile with 2.7.

Here is your code, reformatted with that in mind:

```
def get_primes(n): 
    """
    Find all prime numbers between 0 and n
    Args:
        n (int): The input number to find primes up to.
    """
    primes = [True] * (n / 2)
    for i in range(int((n / 2 - 1) / 2) >> 1):
        for j in range((i * (i + 3) << 1) + 3, n / 2, (i << 1) + 3): 
            primes[j] = False
    return [2] + [((i << 1) + 3) for i in range(n / 2) if (primes[i])]

# test function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_primes(input())
```

Answer (score -3):

If your **primary goal** is the shortest program. Then you can use regular expressions for a much shorter program to find primes.

So in python it looks like:

```
def is_prime(n):
    import re
    for i in range(n):
       if re.match(r'1?$|(11+?)\1+$', '1' * i) is None:
           print i
```

Comment: This fails to improve on all the other goals, though: faster, more memory-efficient, more scalable. I can't recommend it as good code.

Comment: More readable easier to remember and reproduce accurately. And has a reasonable runtime for small numbers.

Comment: Have you tested your code with a number like 10? Also, an `is*` function should return a Boolean value instead of printing things.